# Sum of the Expected Value of a Quotient. Is putting the Sample Size equal to 1 allowed?

Tags: expected-value

Let $Y_1,...,Y_n$ be independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) (standard/regular) inverse Gaussian random variables with parameters $\mu>0$ and $\lambda>0$. It is given that $E(Y_i)=\mu$.

While doing computations I arrive at the expression $\sum_{i=1}^n\left[E\left(\frac{1}{Y_i}\right)\right] = \frac{n}{\lambda} + \frac{n}{\mu}$.

In the answers provided to me they state that it now immediately follows that $E\left(\frac{1}{Y_i}\right) = \frac{1}{\lambda} + \frac{1}{\mu}$.

Why and how does this follows?

By just setting $n=1$ at both sides of the $=$-sign, or are there other (intermediate) steps to take to arrive at this result?

Comment: How did you arrive "$\sum_{i=1}^n\left[E\left(\frac{1}{Y_i}\right)\right] = \frac{n}{\lambda} + \frac{n}{\mu}$"?

Comment: @user158565 It's a long story. I first - correctly - derived the Fisher score function and then applied the property that the expected value of the Fisher score function should be equal to $\mathbf{0}$. The first element of the Fisher score function (it's a multivariate function) is zero by itself, but the second one is zero if and only if this condition holds. The answers provided to me state that $-\frac{n}{2\mu} - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \left[E\left(\frac{1}{Y_i}\right)\right] + \frac{n}{2\lambda} + \frac{n}{\mu} = 0$, from which my equality follows.

Comment: Subsequently, the answers immediately state that 'This implies that $E\left(\frac{1}{Y_i}\right) = \frac{1}{\mu} + \frac{1}{\lambda}$. How/why? (I have never encountered something like this before).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on the fact that

$$E(f(X_i))=E(f(X_j))$$ given $X_i$ is iid for $i=1,2,...n$.

Given $\sum_{i=1}^n\left[E\left(\frac{1}{Y_i}\right)\right] = \frac{n}{\lambda} + \frac{n}{\mu}$ is correct, we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left[E\left(\frac{1}{Y_i}\right)\right] = nE\left(\frac{1}{Y_i}\right)= \frac{n}{\lambda} + \frac{n}{\mu}$$

So

$$E\left(\frac{1}{Y_i}\right)= \frac{1}{\lambda} + \frac{1}{\mu}$$

Comment: So, basically, you are saying that since $\sum_{i=1}^n \left[E \left(\frac{1}{Y_i} \right)\right]$ is constant, $E \left(\frac{1}{Y_i} \right)$ has to be constant, and that's why we have that $\sum_{i=1}^n \left[E \left(\frac{1}{Y_i} \right)\right] = n \cdot E \left(\frac{1}{Y_i} \right)$?

Comment: For frequentest, expectation of the random is the unknown parameter (constant) of the function of the parameters (constant). Anyway the expectation is the unknown constant.  There is no random component in the expectation.

Comment: I understand. I was so confused here (probably due to the summation operator) but thanks to you it is perfectly clear now.